# Rails upload image and reposition like facebook

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, image-uploading

I am making an app in which I want to upload cover just like Facebook and reposition it.

Can anyone tell me how I can make it possible in Rails?

This is the demo link:

http://demos.9lessons.info/ajaximageupload/index_bg_drag.php

This would be a really great help if someone can tell me how I can do the same in Rails. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can follow following tutorial for image cropping and other stuff :

https://railskumar.wordpress.com/2015/05/01/crop-zoom-and-rotate-image-using-carrierwave/
http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images?view=asciicast

Pro :
http://railscasts.com/episodes/182-cropping-images-revised?view=asciicast

Whichever tutorial you follow just submit form using `:remote => true` . But you can not submit image in simple form you either need to submit it in a iFrame or through flash. To solve this problem use `remotipart` [gem](https://github.com/JangoSteve/remotipart).

Same example image upload [here](http://glacial-chamber-7467.herokuapp.com/).